# How to modify QtWebEngine behavior when link is clicked?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtwebengine

I have `WebEngineView`:

```
WebEngineView {
    anchors.fill: parent
}
```

If I open, e.g. Google search page, and click on the links, nothing happens. But if I click right mouse button and select "follow link", the link is opened. How can I make QtWebEngine follow links on click? Also I need to open a new app instance if link's `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `createWindow` function of QWebEngineView , it's a virtual protected function of the form :

`QWebEngineView* createWindow(QWebEnginePage::WebWindowType type)`

For more info you can visit [createWindow qt5.8 doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#createWindow) and you can also see the example code of simple browser here [simple browser qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-simplebrowser-example.html) .

Hope it helps ! Happy coding !